# I am trying to make rock scissors paper game , hovering over on the buttons is not converting cursor to pointer type , shared some part of code

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

*HTML code, It is not the full HTML code , but the part of it rest of the code works fine*

*Here is the that is linked to above HTML file CSS code, the issue is cursor is not converting to pointer when we put the cursor on it*

```css
.options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.options button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="game">
  <div class="options">
    <button class="rock">rock</button>
    <button class="paper">paper</button>
    <button class="scissors">scissors</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: In the snippet works....

Answer (score 1):

This code works and there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

hmm it seems your code have no problem can you send screen shot
or at least change it to this code

```css
.options button:hover  {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```